# UWP wont locate the table in sqlite database. why so?

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I am following a tutorial on Microsoft website but the sqlite engine wont find the table in my db file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

```
 public static List<String> GetData()
        {
            List<String> entries = new List<string>();

            using (SqliteConnection db =
                new SqliteConnection("Filename=MyQuoteAppDB.db"))
            {
                db.Open();

                SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                    ("SELECT AuthorName from Author", db);

                SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (query.Read())
                {
                    entries.Add(query.GetString(0));
                }

                db.Close();
            }

            return entries;
        }
    }
```

I get the following error : Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Author'.'

I have actually imported table Author via a Converter.exe and created a db file

Comment: Are you trying to read the "Author" table from an existing database (created in some other application maybe) ?

Comment: I have imported the sqlite Db from Db browser sqlite app. I can create a new table and read it. But the imported tables can't be read. I have tried reading with schema as well. But I can't read from the imported tables.

Comment: hi @sly_Chandan Could you share a code sample that could reproduce this issue for us?

Comment: I am following the same steps mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: I tried importing a sqlite db and I can confirm that this issue is reproducible . My approach was to get the db file using a `FileOpenPicker` then copying the file to the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` (to make sure app has full access to the db) and tried executing a `Select` statement on an existing table, but it kept throwing the same "Table not found" exception which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: What do you mean? This is a bug in the framework?

Comment: I see the entries for new table but I don't see the new table in Db browser

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. We are missing something or maybe there is a specific way to read an existing db table .

Answer (score -2):

It look like the table "Author" is not present in your database file.

Comment: Its there! The code works for a new table but not for an existing table